# Azure SQL Database failing to scale up. Error requesting ARM API returned 'HTTP 0 error. Azure Portal

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to scale my Azure SQL database from S0, 10DTU's upwards to S2 through the Azure Portal but it keeps on failing with the following error:

Scale database error

Failed to scale from Standard S0: 10 DTUs, 100 GB storage to Standard S2: 50 DTUs, 100 GB storage for database: SynapseDemo. Error code: . Error message: Error requesting ARM API. 'PATCH [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/4f7ac0ca-dc6b-4e32-9844-5dc8bed80e31/resourceGroups/SynapseDemo/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sentronics/databases/SynapseDemo?api-version=2022-08-01-preview'](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/4f7ac0ca-dc6b-4e32-9844-5dc8bed80e31/resourceGroups/SynapseDemo/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sentronics/databases/SynapseDemo?api-version=2022-08-01-preview%27) returned 'HTTP 0 error'

I am the subscription and resource group owner.

Scaling up and down has worked in the past but recently started failing even with multiple attempts.

Comment: Cross-posted to [Azure SQL Database Scaling Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1460730/azure-sql-database-scaling-error).

Comment: Seems to be a browser/cache issue, was using portal on Chrome without success but scaling worked on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments @Darius Raubenheimer, Posting this for the benefit of the community.

> Azure SQL Database failing to scale up. Error requesting ARM API returned 'HTTP 0 error. Azure Portal

***The cause of issue is mainly because following reasons:***

1. *Insufficient [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-scale?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#permissions) as **Azure RBAC permissions are needed to scale the database, specifically the Contributor, SQL DB Contributor role, or SQL Server Contributor Azure RBAC roles.***
2. *Make sure your database does not have any **Read-only lock***
3. *Azure Portal fails to perform few operations due to cache issues in the browser, Thus its recommended to clear your browser cache, use latest version of the Browsers supported [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-supported-browsers-devices#recommended-browsers). Or use Incognito Window (Chrome) or InPrivate Tab (Edge) and log in to your account again to perform the task.*